# Question on banach space over an extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$

Tags: functional-analysis, number-theory, banach-spaces, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact locally  $\Bbb{Q}_p$  analytic group. Let $E$ be a finite extension of 
 $\Bbb{Q}_p$ with ring of integers $O$.
Let $M$ be a $O[G]$ module.

I was reading an article which says :
Let $M$ be a p-adically complete and separated as a $O$ module. What does it mean to be separated. Also how to show that the image of $M$ in $E \otimes_{O} M$ by the natural map becomes an $O$ lattice whose gauge is the required complete norm on  $E \otimes_{O} M$ . In this case $E \otimes_{O} M$ is equipped with a natural $E$- banach space structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separated means that the intersection $\cap p^{n} M$ is zero. Where the notation $p^{n}M$ means the submodule of M of the form $(p^{n}) \dot M$. As a $\mathcal{O}$ module the ring $\mathcal{O}_{E}$ is free of finite rank and hence $\mathcal{O}_{E} \otimes M$ is a finite direct sum of $M$. The $\mathcal{O}_{E}$ module structure can be seen explicitly by choosing a basis of $\mathcal{O}_{E}$ over $\mathcal{O}$ (which can be chosen to be cyclic by normal basis theorem). The $E$ module structure comes by inverting the uniformizer.

To answer you comment: Note that $\mathcal{O}$ is a $k$ banach space (where $k$) is the residue field of E with the $p-adic$ norm. If M is finitely generated then there is a presentation of $M$ as a quotient of a free module $\mathcal{O}^{n}$. $\mathcal{O}^{n}$ is a Banach space and it is a fact that any ideal is closed in the $p-adic$ topology so $M$ has a well defined Banach space structure.

Because $\mathcal{O}$ is complete hence $\mathcal{O}^{n}$ and $M$ are complete.

Comment: But why is it a banach space. What is the norm and how is it complete?

Comment: What I call $O$ is the ring of integers of $E$. The tensor product we are looking for is $E$ tensor with $M$ over the ring of integers of $E$. So $M$ cannot be assumed to be finitely generated.

Comment: If $M$ is not a finitely  generated $O$ module then it is a colimit of a fintely generated $O$ module but the tensor product commutes with colimits so it suufices to understand the Banach space structure on finitely generated $O$ modules. BTW you can take $G= E^{\star}$ and M= $E$ as a example of finitely generated module.